# MediaWiki Template:Notice import looks different that mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I imported Template:Notice from Mediawiki to my mediawiki instance, but it doesn't look the same.

MediaWiki:

[image]

My instance:

[image]

I tried copying Module:Message box/ambox.css to my Mediawiki:Common.css and have set:

```
$wgUseInstantCommons = true;
```

What else do I need to do?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now with no additional changes.  Something must have been caching.